Assembly jump instructions don't seem to work
bits 64
default rel

section .data
    fmt db "%s", 0xd, 0xa, 0
    err db "Correct usage: echo <string>"

section .text
    extern printf
    extern ExitProcess
    global main

main:
    ;Set up stack
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32
    
    ;Save cli args in r11 and r12
    mov r11, rcx ;argc
    mov r12, rdx ;argv

    cmp r11, 2
    jl .wrong_num_of_args_error

    mov rbx, 1
    ;Loop through argv
    .loop:
        cmp rbx, r11
        je .end
        mov rdx, [r12 + rbx * 8]
        mov rcx, fmt

        call printf
        inc rbx
        cmp rbx, r11
        jl .loop
        jmp .end

    ;Exit
    .end:
        xor rax, rax
        call ExitProcess

    .wrong_num_of_args_error:
        ;Prepare to call printf
        mov rcx, err
        call printf
        
        ;Exit
        xor rax, rax
        call ExitProcess

The loop in this code runs for too long. I tried many ways but I can't get it to work. The logic looks sound too. I'm using x64 asm with win64calling convention
I tried decrementing r11 (the argc), mov rbx, 2 (rbx is the counter)
I got all the args I passed to it and two (null)s

Are you sure argc and argv are passed to main in rcx, rdx?  Have you checked this out in the debugger?  I thought you needed to use something like GetMainArgs.

R11 is not preserved across calls. See documentation. As such call printf can change it.

@David Wohlferd I'm sure that args are passed to main in rcx, rdx. Because it prints all of the args and then a few nulls

@Jester you're right. r11 isn't preserved. I'll try changing it and see what happens

@Jester thanks a lot. It works perfectly now.
